# SSH port forwarding remote to local in nested server for postgres database in one line

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding

I have 2 servers as
**ubuntu@example1.com** and **ubuntu@example2.com**, I want to connect to ubuntu@example2.com but I cannot connect to it directly due to restrictions, I have to first connect to ubuntu@example1.com and then I have to connect to example2.com from example1.com.

Now in my local I want to connect my application to remote psql server which is on ubuntu@example2.com:5432. For this I have to do following steps.

1. SSH into example1.com

   ```
   ssh ubuntu@example1.com
   ```
2. Now from example1, After ssh, go inside example1.com and then forward port 5432 from example2 to 5434 of example1 by entering following in example1.com:

   ```
   ssh -L 5434:localhost:5432 ubuntu@example2.com
   ```
3. Now from my local, in another terminal tab, I have to type following command to forward port 5434 of example1.com (which is coming from 5432 of example2) to my local 5432.

   ```
   ssh -L 5432:localhost:5434 ubuntu@example1.com
   ```

Now finally in my local, my application can connect to localhost with port 5432, as if psql is running locally.

I want to make this whole into a single command so that I can do it in just one step and also stop it in one step, rather than doing the above 3 steps because again and again I have to type so much, I am willing to create a executable file (like a shell script) as well.

So far I tried doing this:

```
ssh -L 5432:localhost:5434 ubuntu@example1.com ssh -L 5434:localhost:5542 -N ubuntu@example2.com
```

This is exactly the solution I want, it works like a charm, **IT WORKS**, but , there is a **BUT** now. And that but is, **when I do CTRL + C, it kills my local ssh connection for 5434 of example1 to my local 5432, but it does not kill the connection between example2.com and example1.com** , due to this when I run the above command again it gives me this error:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5434
```

And then I have to change port again, and then again it hangs there, and when I do CTRL+C again it would block that port,

**So what I need?**

So I need another way of port forwarding or I need a way to kill the connection between example1.com and example2.com, I just need one step (single line) to start and 1 step to stop (single line).

So far I have been killing these connections by doing `ps -aux | grep 5434` from inside of example1.com and the killing it using kill command.

My local SSH config (**~/.ssh/config**)

```
Host *.*.*.*
   StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host *
        ServerAliveInterval 50
        ServerAliveCountMax 10
        ForwardAgent yes
```

Edit #1:

```
ssh -J ubuntu@example1.com ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -N ubuntu@example2.com
```

Tried the above command but I am getting this error:

```
open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Probably this has something to do with example2 being a private IP, only example1 is a public IP (not sure if this is the problem).

Comment: "Probably this has something to do with `example2` being a private IP, only `example1` is a public IP" – Irrelevant. The mechanism of `-J` resolves the target host on the last (in your case the only) jump host. The target host may not be reachable from your local computer, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `ssh` running on `example1.com` survives.

Simplify the whole setup. An elegant way is to use [`ssh -J`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J):

> `-J destination`
> Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host described by `destination` and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.

```
ssh -J ubuntu@example1.com ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -N ubuntu@example2.com
```

This is *not* equivalent to connecting from your local computer to `example1.com` and then from `example1.com` to `example2.com`. It's equivalent to connecting from your local computer to `example1.com` and then from your local to `example2.com` (using packets forwarded through `example1.com`). No SSH client is invoked on `example1.com`. This means:

- The credentials for `example2.com` must come from your local computer, not from `example1.com`. If the restrictions you mentioned mean the credentials come from `example1.com` and you cannot change this, then this approach cannot be used.
- Neither `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` nor `~/.ssh/config` from `example1.com` matters. Configure the access to `example2.com` in your *local* config. Note you can specify [`ProxyJump`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump) in the config:

  ```
  Host example2.com
       ProxyJump example1.com
  ```

  If you do this, you will no longer need `-J` when connecting to `example2.com`:

  ```
  ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -N ubuntu@example2.com
  ```

---

In case of `administratively prohibited: open failed` (or if you cannot or don't want to use `-J`/`ProxyJump` for whatever reason), revert to your original command (we will fix it in a moment).

`administratively prohibited: open failed` in your case means `-J` cannot establish a TCP forwarding from your local computer to `example2.com` via `example1.com`, because the administrator of `example1.com` disallows this. Still your original command succeeds in forwarding ports. Possibly [`PermitOpen localhost:*`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitOpen) is in use. Let's fix your original command then.

Your original command is in a form:

```
ssh     … ubuntu@example1.com ssh …
```

Fix it like this:

```
ssh -tt … ubuntu@example1.com ssh …
```

The difference is `-tt` will force tty allocation for `ssh` running on `ubuntu@example1.com` (regardless if your local `ssh` has tty). Now if you terminate the local `ssh` then the remote `ssh` will receive [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP):

> On POSIX-compliant platforms, `SIGHUP` ("signal hang up") is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed.

The `ssh` running on `example1.com` will gracefully exit upon `SIGHUP`. You will no longer need to kill it manually.

Your original command allocates no tty, so this useful mechanism does not apply. Adding `-tt` changes this.

Comment: this is the best, I don't want even want to go to example2 from example1, going from my local is even better!!!! thanks for this, this is exactly what I need, I will test this and get back to you later and accept it if it works and confirm.

Comment: Getting this error:
`channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`
Not sure if this has something to do with, example2.com being a private IP, only example1.com is the public IP, thats why I cannot directly connect to example2.com maybe, not sure.

Comment: I have added my local ssh config in the question edit as well, for your reference

Comment: @user1735921 The answer now addresses the issue.