# rsync through ssh proxy using a key that is on the proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, rsync, scp

I am trying to copy files using `rsync` from a server A, to a server C, through a bastion server B.

```
A -> B -> C
```

This can be achieved normally through using the `-e` option, like: `rsync -e 'ssh user@host' ...`. However, I can't figure out or find examples on how to do this when the server B has the key that server C is expecting. All search results assume server A has the key, and that key is on both B and C.

I can successfully use this ssh command to use the remote key:

```
ssh -t user@hostB ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/private_key user@hostC
```

But I am not able to translate this into a valid `rsynd -e '...'` command. One main issue is that the above changes the ssh startup shell using `-t`, which I don't think is the correct approach. I've also tried using the JumpHost ssh option:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -J user@hostB' ...
```

This is also unsuccessful.

While using `rsync` is preferred, if this isn't possible then a solution that uses `scp` will also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

When you use `rsync -e ssh local_path userX@serverX:remote_path`, `rsync` takes the option-argument of `-e` (here `ssh`) and adds `userX@serverX` and more to build the command it will use. In effect the command will be like:

```
ssh userX@serverX …
```

where `…` denotes `rsync`-specific command to be run on the remote side.

You want the command to be:

```
ssh user@hostB ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/private_key user@hostC …
```

so your `rsync` command needs to be:

```
rsync -e 'ssh user@hostB ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/private_key' local_path user@hostC:remote_path
```

---

#### Additional explanation

You must not use `ssh -t`. The command that worked for you:

> ```
> ssh -t user@hostB ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/private_key user@hostC
> ```

spawns an interactive shell which works well when there is a tty allocated on `hostB` and on `hostC`. `ssh` won't allocate a tty on the remote side automatically if you specify a command; otherwise it will. In the above command the outer `ssh` runs a command (`ssh -i …`) and it wouldn't allocate a tty on `hostB`, if you didn't use `-t`. The inner `ssh` sees no command, so it allocates a tty on `hostC` automatically before running a shell there.

An interactive shell needs a tty. It's different with `rsync`, it needs a raw data channel; changes and translations imposed by tty will break things. That's why you mustn't use `-t` at all. Then each `ssh` will see some command specified (in case of the inner `ssh` it will be the command added by `rsync`), so there will be no tty allocated on `hostB` and no tty allocated on `hostC`.

Why `-J` is not a solution is explained at the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1581104/432690).

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, this works wonderfully. I missed the second ```shh``` in my command. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

After researching further, this looks like it is an insecure process. Instead, I think the correct solution is to add the key on server A to both server B and C as authorized keys. After that, this solution should be used: https://superuser.com/a/1115998/1621610