# stopping ssh process that is sent to background without corrupting stdout

Tags: bash, ssh, script, tail, tshark

My script aims to extract a text log file using `tail -f` and a wireshark trace using `tshark`. But I don't know if these are the best options for my goal.

My script has to `ssh` into a machine (which I call server) and then from that machine it `ssh` into another (called blade), so I created these 2 functions to streamline sending commands:

```bash
processIDs=()

# sends command $2 to server $1, piping output to file $3 on local machine
server_cmd() {
    ssh -i /home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa root@$1 $2 1>>$3 2>>$errorOutput &
    processIDs+=($!)
}

# sends command $3 to blade $2 of server $1, piping output to file $4 on local machine
blade_cmd() {
    server_cmd $1 "ssh root@$2 \"$3\"" $4
}
```

The process IDs get stored into an array every time I send an `ssh` call into the background.

On my script I make a variable number of calls (depending on user choices) to the `blade_cmd` function:

```bash
blade_cmd $server_ip $server_blade_ip "tail -f \\\$(ls -1tr ${path}_Debug_* | tail -1)" debug.log
blade_cmd $server_ip $server_blade_ip "tail -f \\\$(ls -1tr ${path}_Report_* | tail -1)" report.log

blade_cmd $server_ip $server_blade_ip "tshark -i eth7 -w -" tshark.pcap
```

Then perform the actions that generate the logs/traces, and then kill the processes like so:

```bash
# kill all generated processes on the array
for i in ${!processIDs[@]}; do
    kill ${processIDs[i]}
    wait ${processIDs[i]} 2>>$errorOutput
done
```

But with this setup the processes on the remote machines don't get killed and are left hanging.

The solution that I found to killing the processes is to call `ssh` with the `-tt` flag to force the `tty` which does fix the problem of not propagating the kill that comes from the local machine but then the logs/traces I receive get corrupted by the login banner and the various newlines, which render the logs and especially the `tshark` traces useless.

I require some guidance on how to go forward with this.

Comment: Fast remarks: (1) [Quote properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). It's not easy because you need to quote for the local shell (interpreting the script), for a remote shell on *server* and for a remote shell on *blade*. The syntax `${var@Q}` may be handy. (2) `ssh -J` or equivalent "manual" setup can circumvent the shell on *server* and thus simplify quoting. See the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1581104). (3) Connection sharing (`ssh -M`) can reduce the number of actual connections. (4) See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, will see if these can help me fix or better handle my problem.

Comment: Have you ever looked into ansible or chef or another automation tool?

Comment: Since I can't install software on the local machine, I can only make use of bash scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my tests a remote `tshark -w - …` exits automatically when the local `ssh` exits, even if I chain `ssh`s like you do; at least when `tshark` tries to keep writing. I think it's the mechanism described here: [*Why isn't `tail -f … | grep -q …` quitting when it finds a match?*](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690)

Note the first write after the local `ssh` exits will probably only cause the intermediate `ssh` (on *server*) to exit, the next write will cause `tshark` to exit.

It's similar with `tail -f` on *blade*, except this `tail` may (or may not) be "smart" and detect the broken pipe (see the linked answer). Still the intermediate `ssh` is not that smart.

So yes, in some circumstances "the processes on the remote machines […] are left hanging".

There is a trick to make remote `tshark` or `tail -f` exit just after the local `ssh` exits. You cannot use this trick with remote commands that should read from stdin (i.e. ultimately from stdin of the local `ssh`), but since `tshark` and `tail -f` don't use their stdin, *in this case* the trick will be useful. This is the trick:

On *blade*, instead of `tshark …` run:

```
# shell code for blade
tshark … & cat >/dev/null; kill "$!"
```

Note locally you need to adjust the quoting so `$!` is expanded on *blade*, not earlier. For brevity I decided to post the command in a form a shell on *blade* should get.

`tshark …` runs now in the background on *blade*, this shouldn't prevent it from working though. `cat` ultimately reads from stdin of the local `ssh` and it will sit there until the local `ssh` exits or its stdin breaks or is depleted. If the local `ssh` exits or its stdin breaks or is depleted, the `cat` will get an EOF condition and it will exit. Then `kill` will kill `tshark` on *blade*.

When `tshark`, `cat` and `kill` are no more, the shell on *blade* exits and the relevant instance of `sshd` on *blade* exits, so `ssh` on *server* also exits. It's clean.

The same trick can be used to make `tail -f …` exit.

Now we need to take care of the local side.

The remote `cat` will read what the local `ssh` reads. Without redirection the local `ssh` will consume the stdin of the local script (stdin may be a terminal, a regular file or whatever). In general you may want not to let the local `ssh` consume the stdin of the script. Also if EOF condition happens prematurely then `cat` will exit prematurely; we want it to exit only after the local `ssh` exits, not when local stdin is depleted. For these reasons it's good to connect stdin of the local `ssh` to something else than the stdin of the script. It cannot be `/dev/null` because EOF would happen immediately. It shouldn't be `/dev/zero` because it would transfer zero bytes in vain. It could be `tail -f /dev/null`:

```
# locally inside your function
tail -f /dev/null | ssh … &
```

but then `$!` would tell you the PID of `ssh` and after killing `ssh` this local `tail` would remain, unless it's "smart" (again, see the linked answer). Only if your local `tail` is "smart" then this will be a clean way that doesn't leave hanging processes.

Alternatively you can use a dummy fifo. You should open it for reading and writing beforehand, so nothing stalls. Still, there is no need to pass anything through the fifo. Example:

```sh
# locally
mkfifo dummy
exec 3<>dummy
rm dummy

# then inside your function
<&3 ssh … &
```

You can use the same fifo for many instances of `ssh`. In the example I unlinked the fifo from the directory just after opening the file descriptor, so there is no need for maintenance later. The kernel will truly get rid of the fifo when it's no longer in use.

One way or another (i.e. with "smart" `tail` or a fifo) it's now enough to kill `ssh` locally and the remote `cat` on *blade* will see EOF and exit, and things on *blade* and *server* will happen as described above.

Comment: Works perfectly tyvm, if you could give me some resources to learn more about dummy fifo's would be great. This script has been a learning journey for me :D

Comment: @Fixenet It's not an official term. I called the fifo "dummy fifo" because we don't use it to transfer data (and this is what pipes usually are for). We don't even use it to "transfer" an EOF condition! (EOF `cat` "sees" happens because the local `ssh` gets killed, not "from" `dummy`). Technically our `dummy` fifo is a normal named pipe, we needed it just to *be* there. We needed an entity that doesn't give us EOF when we try to read, but also doesn't give us data. A terminal where we *don't type* is similar. I didn't use the terminal because *maybe* you want to use it for something else.